# Firebase more complex queries (Integration with ElasticSearch)

Tags: android, elasticsearch, firebase

My question is this, I´ve seen the FlashLight library which integrates ElasticSearch with Firebase, the problem is that it´s based on node.js and I only have experience with Java, is there another library similar to FlashLight where the code is based in java or maybe a tutorial on setting up ElasticSearch with Firebase using Java?

Comment: @Adrea currently, am in the same dilemma that you were 1 month ago. did you find any solution?

Comment: I´ve used Algolia instead of ElasticSearch, it´s much simpler although is not free

Comment: You should answer yourself and accept your own answer so other know it has been solved

Comment: the question has not being answered, I just used a different method, but the question remains

Comment: I'm an iOS developer, Andrea, and I feel you! I've been asking this since last year :( I've successfully ran Flashlight in my local but I have no idea how to make a basic REST API to connect it to Flashlight.